# Purchase real Ether and add to base/default account

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ether, contract-deployment, microsoft-azure

I created an Ethereum Consortium Leader instance on Microsoft Azure and they provided us with an Admin site and RPC endpoint:

http://someName.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/

http://someName.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8545

Why these are publicly accessible ? Is it because its a test account ? How can I create a real Ethereum blockchain on Azure and put some real Ether in it after purchasing from crypto-currency exchange ?

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum Consortium Network is a **private blockchain network** and it does nothing with actual Ethereum. Microsoft provide the blockchain as BaaS on Azure platform.

<sub>BaaS - Backend-as-a-Service</sub>

Comment: So, how can I create a system where I buy real Ether and credit some users  with some Ether if they win quiz? I want to do it using web3 or curl request(transfer real Ether from main account)

Comment: For real ether you don't need your own consortium.  Just use public network and deploy your own smart contracts to it.